# Using many resistors to scale down AC voltage

Tags: voltage-divider

I've heard it's common practice to use many resistors in series within a voltage divider to scale down an AC voltage for both power dissipation and capacitance considerations (using 10, 100MOhm resistors in series instead of one 1GOhm in a voltage divider.)

Is there any type of formula/reference document out there that states how many smaller resistors is enough? For example:

Situation 1: I want a 1kV peak voltage-measuring circuit to scale down to 2.5V using a 1GOhm resistor. My thoughts were to use 10 100Mohm resistors, but am not sure if this is overkill.

Situation 2: I want to measure up to 347VAC using a 100MOhm resistor. Should I use 10 10Mohm resistors, or again is this too much?

I realize this will depend on the power rating and parasitic capacitance values of the resistors I choose, but also feel there must be some tribal knowledge answer to this as well.

Comment: One of the problems with large value resistors is that material on the surface of the PCB (dust, a little bit of moisture, finger oil) can create what under other circumstances would be a high-resistive leakage path around the resistor that reduces the effective resistance.  Multiple resistors are one way to help this by making the leakage path longer.  There are also layout techniques that can help.

Comment: And another point.  You want to use at least two resistors in parallel in the lower leg of your voltage divider.  This is to prevent the high voltage from showing up at the input to the measurement circuit should the single lower resistor open up, the solder joint fails, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With resistor values that high the power dissipation will almost certainly not be a problem. Voltage capability will be though.

The voltage rating of a resistor depends largely on its physical construction. Large through hole resistors are often rated for 250V or higher. The power rating will also depend upon the physical size so they will tend to go hand-in-hand.

Some resistors designed for high-voltage can withstand thousands of volts. They will be physically large and expensive though.

At the other extreme small surface mount resistors (0603, 0402) will usually have a rating of only 50V.

You will need to select the quantity of resistors that will meet your upper voltage limit. For example if the the resistors tolerate 250V and you have a 1kV peak input you need at least 4 resistors - maybe 5 or 6.

If you select 5 resistors and each one is 100 MOhm the current will 2 microamps. The total power dissipation will only be 2mW. This is only 400uW per resistor - insignificant and not an issue.

You don't say what bandwidth you require from the attenuator. With a value of 100MOhm per resistor, you will almost certainly need to put balancing capacitors across each resistor because of the uncertainty of the parasitic capacitances.

A typical capacitance for a 0.25W through-hole resistor might be 0.25pF plus another 0.5pF for the via and trace on the PCB. In general, the approach is to swamp that with a real capacitor that is much larger, eg 5pF or 10pF. Some designers have built this capacitor into the PCB, but this will require some experimentation and care.

In this case, the bottom resistor of the will need to be ~1.25MOhm to get the 2.5V output that you need. The capacitance across it should be such that you achieve the same time constant as the other RC combinations so the attenuation of the entire divider is independent of frequency.

To match the 10pF 100MOhm combination on each resistor will require ~800pF across the bottom resistor. You may need a trimmer capacitance to adjust the compensation (just like on a scope probe).

As @Spehro Pefhany comments even 100MOhm is a rather high value and out of the normal range of resistors. Unless you really need that high an input resistance using resistors of 10MOhms or lower will be much cheaper and provide you with better selection and availability. The power dissipation will increase and although not likely to be an issue in this example might be in others.

Comment: This is perfect thank you! So if my Power and Voltage requirements are in check I could get away with using just one, 1GOhm, or one, 100MOhm resistor? This is just for a 60Hz AC Power Measuring circuit

Comment: Give some consideration of environment too. No doubt, voltage ratings in spec sheets use "clean" resistors. If they (or their mounting fixture) can attract dust or other contaminants, de-rating is in order, especially for large-value resistors.

Comment: Ah ok that's a great point. I'm confused about these 'swamping capacitors,' though. If connected in parallel with the resistors this would make the total capacitance higher, isn't that not beneficial? Looks like they're proposing impedance matching

Comment: @cdubs - the issue is that the parasitic capacitances are not well defined and may vary from unit to unit. A swamping capacitor will have a defined value. It will increase the input capacitance to the divider which is somewhat undesirable but for this example with 5 x 10pF capacitors in series would only add 2pF to the total input capacitance - this is probably less than that the rest of the layout.

Comment: @cdubs - you could use a single resistor if it meets the voltage ratings. At 60Hz you may be able to avoid any compensation capacitors although the bandwidth of a 1GOhm resistor with 1pF shunt capacitance is only ~150Hz. So even the third harmonic of the input signal will be accentuated. 100MOhm would have a higher flat bandwidth.

Comment: Ok sweet, thank you! I'll go with a single 100MOhm, but look into other options for the 1GOhm configuration.

Comment: @KevinWhite: do you have a solid resource you could recommend on PCB/circuit design in general? Curious where you all gained the knowledge needed to answer these questions. Figure most is work experience, but I do not work in PCB design

Comment: @cdubs - not really I'm afraid. A great deal of it is gained through many years of experience.

Comment: @cdubs - You might want to try the website of some of the bigger name printed wiring board manufacturers, like TTM-Unicircuits for design guidelines.

Comment: Ah ok shoot that's what I figured. @SteveSh thanks, I'll check them out!

Answer (score 0):

Voltage rating is a more serious consideration, specifically transient voltage rating, which should be in the kV.

A single resistor (particularly a special high voltage type) may be fine, or not, depending on what standard(s) your product must meet, and what mitigation you implement in the product (E.g., TVS or MOV or GDT or low pass filter).

Of course, the required power dissipation capability must also be reliably met.

Comment: Seems unnecessarily high, I would aim more in the 1-10M range. Very high value resistors tend to have various problems such as moisture sensitivity, and relatively large voltage and temperature coefficients.